# How do I pass the dropdown selection value to a button click function in the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have user's country selection dropdown, whose selected value needs to be passed to the submit button ng-click="saveChanges()" function.

What is the proper way to do that? I want be able to know what the user selected in that dropdown.

Comment: Please show some code. What you have done so far ? What you want to achieve ?

Comment: use ng-model value of drop down

Comment: The fact that you're still using an `onClick` function inside an Angularjs application, implies that you don't understand how angular works

Comment: I don't have proper internet to post he detailed question with code. My apologizes. My code is pretty much the same as @Jernej K written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied the example from AngularJS. You have to use the ng-model attribute. This allows you to bind the value to a variable from the controller:

The HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect">
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>repeatSelect = {{data.repeatSelect}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```

The controller class:

```
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
    repeatSelect: null,
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
    ],
   };
   $scope.submit = function() {
     // Logic to handle onClick action by pressing the Button.
     // The ng-model=repeatSelect saved your information to the
     // variable repeatSelect.
     var selectValue = $scope.data.repeatSelect;
     // Do something with selectValue variable
   }
}]);
```

Or if you want to use the `ng-click` method, rather then use a HTML `form`. Then you would have to remove the whole `form` HTML tag and made a change to the button:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="$scope.submit()" />
```

You have to understand that the ng-model binds the value on the spot. So you could easily print that value in a paragraph. And by changing the drop down, the printed value would automatically change.

Just in general I would suggest to first try with the official [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select). In my experience I manage to solve a lot of problems by reading that first.

Comment: How do i access the repeatSelect in side the submit function?

Comment: You could get it like this `var value = $scope.data.repeatSelect;`. This would assign the binded value to value or you just use it straight with `$scope.data.repeatSelect`.

Comment: Here you have a perfect [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope). This show you how to get the values from the scope. Pretty straight-forward.

Comment: your example works perfect when i change the dropdown atleast one time, sometime user may not change the default value on the dropdown and directly click on the save button. Why your logic is not capturing the default dropdown value? Kindly help.

Comment: You could do that by using this code: `ng-selected="$index == 0"`. This would select the first value, because the expression validates if the current index is equal to 0. And here [ng-select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) and the  [index explanation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: So I think you can mark this question as answered, right @JsLearner? Now you know how to get values from input types. `ng-model` works for any input type and binds your values. But a good thing to know also is this binding is a two way street. If you would programmatically add value to the `$scope.data.something = "Some text"` and where you have `data.something`, it would assign that value to a text field for example - of course if the value is bonded to a text field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your continuous help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you need to submit the form after the select box has changed, bind an `ngChange` event to the select that will call the submit function:

```
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-change="saveChanges()" ng-options="....">
```